# Names of System classloaders

Tags: java, applet, classloader

What (default) system classloaders can a Java applet expect to encounter in the Java ecosystem?

For instance, I have seen `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` and `sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader` on my machine. What others can an applet expect to encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few of them I found by giving -verbose option.

- sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader
- java.lang.ClassLoader$3
- java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary
- java.security.SecureClassLoader
- java.net.URLClassLoader

Answer (score 0):

This question is very much JVM-dependent. You can't really know which class loaders a given JVM will use.

Frankly speaking, your application shouldn't be too concerned with this either, especially if your running out of an applet.